# Using latest stable font awesome cdn breaks icons

Tags: font-awesome, blogger, font-awesome-5

I'm setting up blog for my brand on Blogger and I'm trying to link my social
accounts:

I'm going with a CDN link within the header tag:

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

within footer tag:

```
<a class='fb' href='#' rel='nofollow' target='blank' title='Follow Us On Instagram'><i class='fa fa-instagram'/></a>
<a class='twt' href='#' rel='nofollow' target='blank' title='Follow Us On Twitter'><i class='fa fa-twitter'/></a>
<a class='in' href='#' rel='nofollow' target='blank' title='Follow Us On Mastodon'><i class='fa fa-mastodon'/></a>
```

the classes are just for styling. Background color. So it doesn't affect rendering of the icons in any way.

icons render broken:

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome 5 and above needs a `font-weight: 900`

You'll need to add to your CSS something like

```
i.fa,
i.fas {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

or if you use the CSS Pseudo-elements with a class, something like:

```
.your_class::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f007";
  }
```

More info: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use
and
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements